# undefined is not a function (near '...action.account.map...')

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I keep getting this error and I don't know why. All the code seems to be right to me but I can't see my mistake. I'm new to React-Native and New to Redux. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

```
const initialState = {
    account: [],
}
const addAccount = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_ACCOUNT:
            return {
                account: action.account.map(
                    (cb) => newAccount = { id: cb.id.toString(), name: cb.name, imageUri: cb.imageUri, email: cb.email, password: cb.password })

            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
action.payload.account.map
```

Action has two properties payload and type.
type is used in the switch and you send objects as the payload

Comment: Hey  , You really are helping me . I'm new to React-Native and I appreciate all your help. I've seen you answer my questions pretty often . I just wanted to let you know that I really appreciate your help. Is it possible if you could check this question because I can't find my issue. If you don't mind . Please!!. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009527/react-native-expo-image-and-string-not-storing-to-local-database